# Emulator displays a Blue screen and not displaying the google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator, android-mapview

I am trying the very basic google maps api code. But it just gives me a blank blue page.

My program is this

Java code::

```
package com.project1;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Testmap22Activity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(130810,802740);
        MapController mvc = mapview.getController();
        mvc.setCenter(gp);
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

                 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:id="@+id/mapview"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:apiKey="Key"
                 />
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Testmap22Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

All I get is a blank blue page with Zoom enabled.
Need your help on this...

Subbu

Answer (score 1):

```
 android:apiKey="Key"
```

Insert your MD5(map key) instead `"Key"`.

How to get MD5https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I have the actual MD5 key from google. And here is my actual layout. <Code>'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

                 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:id="@+id/mapview"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:apiKey="0F2bFdGVwAfpKIk-XsNQDyAWSFGWvTSkRulG_Ag"
                 />'</Code>

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here

```
 android:apiKey="Key"
```

Refer this link ..here map view is explained step by step 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: Hey, Thanks, but my actual code is, <Code> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

                 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:id="@+id/mapview"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:apiKey="0F2bFdGVwAfpKIk-XsNQDyAWSFGWvTSkRulG_Ag"
                 /></Code>

Comment: change your build target to "Google api"

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you have entered the correct map key and the build target is already set to Google Api. Then there is only one possibility for this blue screen (wrong latitude and longitude arguments):

```
           GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(130810,802740);
```

You have provided wrong arguments in GeoPoint constructor that's why your screen displays blue. Pass correct latitude and longitude in GeoPoint Constructor.